# Define __index inside prototype "constructor" or outside

Tags: lua

I was reading the chapter "Object-Oriented Programming" in "Programming in Lua" on https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html.

In that example, they create this "constructor":

```lua
Account = {balance = 0}
function Account:new (o)
  o = o or {}   -- create object if user does not provide one
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  return o
end
```

I've made some "sintetic benchmarks" on Linux with a simple `time` in a script with 10 million operations like these one. Defining `Account.__index = Account` outside the table initialization is 200ms faster.

My question is, why set the `self.__index` inside this function that will be executed every time this function is called if we can define outside and execute a single time? Heritage maybe?

**EDITED:**

Thank you [luther](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3574628/luther) for the answer, I'll just create an example here for everyone with this doubt:

```lua
local a = {}
a.__index = a
function a:foo()
    return 'foo'
end

function a:new(o)
    print(self)
    o = o or {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    -- self.__index = self
    return o
end

local b = a:new()
-- b.__index = b
function b:bar()
    return 'bar'
end

local z = a:new()
print(z:foo()) -- this will work

local y = b:new()
print(y:foo()) -- attempt to call method 'foo' (a nil value)
print(y:bar()) -- attempt to call method 'bar' (a nil value)
```

Of course `y` will have a metatable with `b` as that table, but `b` doesn't have an `__index` entry, this entry is only inside `b`'s metatable.
If you still want to avoid declaring `__index` inside the "constructor", you'll need specify this in every derivated prototype, or "subclass".

Comment: You seem to be right: `Account.__index = Account` is better.

Comment: It's done to support subclassing `Account`, as shown in the following chapter.

Comment: Yes I read, but I still can define "subclass" and write the same `SubAccount.__index = SubAccount` outside `new` function and got the same behavior.

Comment: If the `new` method assigns `__index`, it will be done for every subobject without having to do it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author of PiL seems to be trying to simplify things by having the `new` method take care of the root object the same way it takes care of all the child objects. This can be confusing to beginners, because it's not immediately clear that `self.__index = self` is often redundant.

Also, it's actually faster to do it this way than to add an `__index` to every object. Remember that in a prototype system, every object is potentially a prototype for other objects. On my machine, with 1e8 trials, the PiL way takes 14 s, while adding `__index` to all objects takes 23 s. A new key means the table has to grow, so it's slower than assigning to a key that already exists.

Confusingly, this PiL section is titled "Classes", but in the first paragraph, he says he's emulating prototype-based languages, where "objects have no classes." This screws up the reader's expectations even further. This section implements a self-replicating object, not a class.

Here's my less confusing, but slower implementation:

```
Account = {balance = 0}
Account.__index = Account

function Account:new (o)
  o = o or {}   -- create object if user does not provide one
  setmetatable(o, self)
  o.__index = o
  return o
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I just using OO terms to make easy to explain myself. But with your example there is no need to add `o.__index = o` because `o` get its metatable from Account table. Or am I wrong? The problem isn't the code by itself, or lua syntax, but a "not so good place" to put a instruction.

Comment: The `o.__index = o` is necessary in case we call `o:new()`, in which case the first `o` will become the next one's metatable. Every object must have an `__index` to act as a prototype.

Comment: Dude, I understood! You're right, we need to chain our `__index` in each derivated object, otherwise the prototype of the prototype will have a metatable without `__index`. Defining hits inside the function that create new tables is just easier than do it in every "`subclass`".